# strange loading xml into as3, root element must be well-formed?

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3, codeigniter

First, I've try to load a xml into a combobox and it goes well (succesfull many times). Then I solve another part of my app. After some new part solved, I try the xml-combobox part again but it gives different result. The error is look like this

```
TypeError: Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
at flash1_fla::MainTimeline/LoadXMLprovALL()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

For the AS3:

```
//some code above here that not related with codes below ...
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,setCB_Prov);
urlXMLprovALL.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,LoadXMLprovALL);

function setCB_Prov(e:Event):void{          
urlRequest.url = "http://localhost/stat.me/index.php/main/get_dataProvider_provinsi";
urlXMLprovALL.load(urlRequest);
}

function LoadXMLprovALL(e:Event):void{
this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, setCB_Prov);
XMLprovALL = new XML(e.target.data);

for(var i:int=0; i<XMLprovALL.provinsi.length(); i++){      
    namaProv[i] = XMLprovALL..nama_provinsi[i];             
    idProv[i] = XMLprovALL..id_provinsi[i];     
    cbProvSkrng.addItem({label: namaProv[i], data:idProv[i]});
} 
cbProvSkrng.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, cbProvSkrngHandler);
}

function cbProvSkrngHandler(e:Event):void{
idProvSkrng = ComboBox(e.target).selectedItem.data; 
}
```

For PHP:

```
<?php $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\n"; 
  $xml .= "<data_provinsi>\n";
  if (is_array($hasil)) {
    foreach ($hasil as $baris) {
    $xml .= "\t<provinsi>\n";
    //$i = 0;
    $xml .= "\t\t <nama_provinsi>" . $baris->nama_provinsi . "</nama_provinsi>\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t <id_provinsi>" . $baris->Id_provinsi . "</id_provinsi>\n";
    //$i++;
    $xml .= "\t</provinsi>\n";
   }
   $xml .= "</data_provinsi>\n";
  } else {
    echo "kosong";
  }
 echo $xml; ?>
```

and the xml if I try it in my browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data_provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Aceh</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>11</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Sumatera Utara</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>12</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Sumatera Barat</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>13</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Riau</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>14</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Jambi</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>15</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Sumatera Selatan</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>16</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Bengkulu</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>17</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Lampung</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>18</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Kepulauan Bangka Belitung</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>19</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Kepulauan Riau</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>21</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Jakarta</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>31</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Jawa Barat</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>32</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Jawa Tengah</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>33</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Yogyakarta</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>34</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Jawa Timur</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>35</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Banten</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>36</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Bali</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>51</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Nusa Tenggara Barat</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>52</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Nusa Tenggara Timur</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>53</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Kalimantan Barat</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>61</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Kalimantan Tengah</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>62</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Kalimantan Selatan</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>63</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Kalimantan Timur</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>64</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Sulawesi Utara</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>71</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Sulawesi Tengah</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>72</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Sulawesi Selatan</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>73</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Sulawesi Tenggara</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>74</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Gorontalo</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>75</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Sulawesi Barat</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>76</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Maluku</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>81</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Maluku Utara</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>82</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Papua Barat</nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>91</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
<provinsi>
     <nama_provinsi>Papua </nama_provinsi>
     <id_provinsi>94</id_provinsi>
</provinsi>
</data_provinsi>
```

Is there something wrong with my code above? how I can solve this error?

[new] Update:

> > > I've try fix some part in my PHP parts and remove some codes that not include in xml constructing parts. Then I didn't get the same error again (sometimes I forget which parts that have changed before). Based on this, I think there is no problem in flash player sand box. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Concrete questions regarding a specific software - like you ask it here: *"Is there any bug in the flash player sandbox?"* - should be directed first of all directly to the vendor of that software and not asked on stackoverflow unless you did that and you have documented the question and response with the vendor of that software.

Comment: XML document cannot have more than one root tag!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is suspected this problem.

Instead of using the XML class, trying storing your results in an XMLList

`TypeError: Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.` occurs when you try to convert a string to XML and the string itself is invalid XML.

For XML to be valid, it should consist of one root node that may or may not contain other nodes or just text.

instead of

```
XMLprovALL = new XML(e.target.data);
```

use

```
var XMLprovALL:XMLList = new XMLList(e.target.data);
```

Comment: Thanks before.
But when I try the xmlList one, the result is same with xml's result. >>> I try this after close-reopen the adobe flash cs5 not in previous condition which the error is appear.

Comment: add a this code `trace(e.target.data);` and see a console. how about?

Comment: it same as the xml above

Comment: Can you link a full source?